# KVM remote-viewer: Force certain keys to stay in host OS

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, virtualization, kvm-virtualization

I am using Ubuntu 14.04, running a Windows 7 guest VM via QEMU/KVM. It's all working fine, I interact with it via Spice using `remote-viewer`. I use Compiz to place the window automatically on the top right desktop (i.e. using workspaces) and keep it running most of the time.

The issue is this: I can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>right</kbd> to get into the remote-viewer window, but then because it captures all input I can't use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>left</kbd> to get back to the other desktops in Ubuntu. I have to use the mouse to click the icon of the program I want to switch to from the launcher, which is annoying and makes it harder to use the workspaces feature.

Is there a way to define keys that aren't passed to the guest OS? I want to have <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> +<kbd>left</kbd>/<kbd>right</kbd>/<kbd>up</kbd>/<kbd>down</kbd> kept within the host so that I can change workspace away from the Windows VM window.

Comment: I realise the [man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/remote-viewer.1.html) mentions the "hotkeys" override, but that doesn't seem to do what I need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't have enough reputation to comment to have to put as an answer, I am looking for a similar solution, I need to send commands to host with keyboard shortcuts, from my research I found there is no way to do it with virt-viewer unless you write a custom app that wraps spice-gtk widget.
Its a shame, I really need this.

---

Edit.
I Just found that it has been filed as a bug/feature request recently https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=93249

---

Edit 2.
According to this commit http://cgit.freedesktop.org/spice/spice-gtk/commit/?id=767e5522f64c115f66f6419abd378ad568e5564e this is possible from spice-gtk v0.27 unfortunately its not in 14.04 repo, but 15.10 ships with v0.28 i am considering upgrading to 15.10

---

Edit 3.
I just tested it in 15.10 and it works, left ctrl+alt releases focus then just do whatever keyboard short-cut you need.
For me this has solved the issue.

Comment: Thanks for finding this out! I tried to get the required packages installed into 14.04, but there were a lot of dependencies so it look like it's too hard to do. I guess I'm just stuck with using the mouse (since I can't upgrade from 14.04 until 15.10 gets approved by my IT department - which it probably won't. Maybe 16.04 will save me.)